# Why am I getting 100% accuracy for SVM, Random-forest Classifier and Logistic Regression?

Tags: machine-learning, python, random-forest, svm

> I'm using an existing disease prediction model to build a chatbot. While I was referring to the model I realized that it has an accuracy of 100%. I'm not quite sure how and why the accuracy is 100%. I've attached herewith the link to the code I'm referring to - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/disease-prediction-using-machine-learning/

> I would be glad if someone could give me some insight on how the accuracy is 100%. Below is the code

```
from cgi import test
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import mode
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, cross_val_score
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, confusion_matrix
import pickle
import requests
import json
import seaborn as sns

# Reading the train.csv by removing the last column since it's an empty column
DATA_PATH = "D:/Diabetdeck-V3/flask-server/dataset/Training.csv"
data = pd.read_csv(DATA_PATH).dropna(axis = 1)

# Checking whether the dataset is balanced or not
disease_counts = data["prognosis"].value_counts()
temp_df = pd.DataFrame({
"Disease": disease_counts.index,
"Counts": disease_counts.values
})

plt.figure(figsize = (18,8))
sns.barplot(x = "Disease", y = "Counts", data = temp_df)
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.show()

# Encoding the target value into numerical value using LabelEncoder
encoder = LabelEncoder()
data["prognosis"] = encoder.fit_transform(data["prognosis"])

X = data.iloc[:,:-1]
y = data.iloc[:, -1]
X_training_data, X_testing_data, y_training_data, y_testing_data =train_test_split(
X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 24)

print(f"Train: {X_training_data.shape}, {y_training_data.shape}")
print(f"Test: {X_testing_data.shape}, {y_testing_data.shape}")

# Defining scoring metric for k-fold cross validation
def cv_scoring(estimator, X, y):
return accuracy_score(y, estimator.predict(X))

# Initializing Models
models = {
"SVC":SVC(),
"Logistic Regression":LogisticRegression(),
"Random Forest":RandomForestClassifier(random_state=18)
}

# Producing cross validation score for the models
for model_name in models:
model = models[model_name]
scores = cross_val_score(model, X, y, cv = 10,
                         n_jobs = -1,
                         scoring = cv_scoring)

print("=="*30)
print(model_name)
print(f"Scores: {scores}")
print(f"Mean Score: {np.mean(scores)}")

# Training and testing SVM Classifier
svm_model = SVC()
svm_model.fit(X_training_data, y_training_data)
preds = svm_model.predict(X_testing_data)
# pickle.dump(svm_model, open('model.pkl','wb'))

print(f"Accuracy on train data by SVM Classifier\
: {accuracy_score(y_training_data, 
svm_model.predict(X_training_data))*100}")

print(f"Accuracy on test data by SVM Classifier\
: {accuracy_score(y_testing_data, preds)*100}")
cf_matrix = confusion_matrix(y_testing_data, preds)
plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
sns.heatmap(cf_matrix, annot=True)
plt.title("Confusion Matrix for SVM Classifier on Test Data")
plt.show()

# Training and testing Logistic Regression
lr_model = LogisticRegression(C=0.1, penalty='l2', 
solver='liblinear')
lr_model.fit(X_training_data, y_training_data)
lr_model.score(X_training_data, y_training_data)
preds = lr_model.predict(X_testing_data)
# pickle.dump(lr_model, open('model.pkl','wb'))

print(f"Accuracy on train data by Logistic Regression\
: {accuracy_score(y_training_data, 
lr_model.predict(X_training_data))*100}")

print(f"Accuracy on test data by Logistic Regression\
: {accuracy_score(y_testing_data, preds)*100}")
cf_matrix = confusion_matrix(y_testing_data, preds)
plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
sns.heatmap(cf_matrix, annot=True)
plt.title("Confusion Matrix for Logistic Regression on Test Data")
plt.show()

# Training and testing Random Forest Classifier
rf_model = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=18)
rf_model.fit(X_training_data, y_training_data)
preds = rf_model.predict(X_testing_data)
# pickle.dump(rf_model, open('model.pkl','wb'))

print(f"Accuracy on train data by Random Forest Classifier\
: {accuracy_score(y_training_data, 
rf_model.predict(X_training_data))*100}")

print(f"Accuracy on test data by Random Forest Classifier\
: {accuracy_score(y_testing_data, preds)*100}")

cf_matrix = confusion_matrix(y_testing_data, preds)
plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
sns.heatmap(cf_matrix, annot=True)
plt.title("Confusion Matrix for Random Forest Classifier on Test Data")
plt.show()

# Training the models on whole data
final_svm_model = SVC()
final_lr_model = LogisticRegression()
final_rf_model = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=18)
final_svm_model.fit(X, y)
pickle.dump(final_svm_model, open('D:/Diabetdeck-V3/flask-server/Model/save/svm/finalsvmmodel.h5', 'wb'))
final_lr_model.fit(X, y)
pickle.dump(final_lr_model, open('D:/Diabetdeck-V3/flask-server/Model/save/lr/finallrmodel.h5', 'wb'))
final_rf_model.fit(X, y)
pickle.dump(final_rf_model, open('D:/Diabetdeck-V3/flask-server/Model/save/rf/finalrfmodel.h5', 'wb'))

# Reading the test data
test_data = pd.read_csv("D:/Diabetdeck-V3/flask-server/dataset/Testing.csv").dropna(axis=1)

test_X = test_data.iloc[:, :-1]
test_Y = encoder.transform(test_data.iloc[:, -1])

# Making prediction by take mode of predictions made by all the classifiers
svm_preds = final_svm_model.predict(test_X)
lr_preds = final_lr_model.predict(test_X)
rf_preds = final_rf_model.predict(test_X)

final_preds = [mode([i,j,k])[0][0] for i,j,
           k in zip(svm_preds, lr_preds, rf_preds)]

print(f"Accuracy on Test dataset by the combined model\
: {accuracy_score(test_Y, final_preds)*100}")

cf_matrix = confusion_matrix(test_Y, final_preds)
plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))

sns.heatmap(cf_matrix, annot = True)
plt.title("Confusion Matrix for Combined Model on Test Dataset")
plt.show()

symptoms = X.columns.values

# Creating a symptom index dictionary to encode the input symptoms into numerical form
symptom_index = {}
for index, value in enumerate(symptoms):
symptom = " ".join([i.capitalize() for i in value.split("_")])
symptom_index[symptom] = index

data_dict = {
"symptom_index":symptom_index,
"predictions_classes":encoder.classes_
}
pickle.dump(data_dict, open('D:/Diabetdeck-V3/flask-server/Model/save/data_dictionary/datadictionary.h5', 'wb'))
```

[image: Screenshot of Accuracy and Output]

> Link to dataset [here](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/kaushil268/disease-prediction-using-machine-learning)